# How to Add $destination to file_get_contents

Tags: php

I want to add $destination in the url of the file_get_contents

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://googleapis.com/json?destinations=New+York+City,NY&units=imperial&origins=&key=AIzaSyDK4HhNWMzdCN5zDOJJI61BFJlKwhvpe4c');
```

to

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://googleapis.com/json?destinations=$destination&units=imperial&origins=&key=AIzaSyDK4HhNWMzdCN5zDOJJI61BFJlKwhvpe4c');
```

Comment: Ok, using which code? What doesn't work? Have you considered using `"` instead of `'` so `$destination` gets expanded? (It doesn't when using single quotes `'`) From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php): "_Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings._"

Answer (score -1):

to evaluate variables inside a string you have to use **double quotation** marks instead of single.
**for example:**

```
$name = "edris";
echo "Hello $name";
```

this code will work fine. becasue in this case we used **"** instead of **'**. I hope this can help.